# Revolving the region bounded by $x^2-y^2=9$ and $y=\pm4$ about both axes individually

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> Evaluate the volume generated by revolving the region bounded by the curve $x^2-y^2=9$ and the lines $y=4$ and $y=-4$ about (1) the $x$-axis and (2) the $y$-axis.

For 'about the $x$-axis', I've tried the cylindrical method and got $254.154$ (correct to 3 dp) and I'm not too sure if I'm correct. These were my steps:
$$V = 2 \pi \int_{-4}^4 (4 + y)(5-\sqrt{9+y^2})dy$$
$$=2\pi \left(80-36\ln \left(3\right)\right)$$
$$=254.154$$
I was thinking that I don't need to take $-\sqrt{9+y^2}$ and just took $\sqrt{9+y^2}$. I'm thinking that it's redundant, since if it rotates it'll rotate 180° to become a cylindrical shape.

Any form of help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the working you did to get to 254?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel added (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt at shell integration of the solid revolved about the $x$-axis involves the wrong integrand (a correct derivation is below). Here's a diagram of the rotated region:

[image]

We can rearrange $x^2-y^2=9$ to yield $x=\sqrt{9+y^2}$.

For rotation about the $x$-axis, the $yz$ plane splits the solid into two equal parts. Then shell integration gives
$$V=2\cdot2\pi\int_0^4xy\,dy$$
$$=2\cdot2\pi\int_0^4y\sqrt{9+y^2}\,dy$$
$$=4\pi\left[\frac13(9+y^2)^{3/2}\right]_0^4$$
$$=4\pi\left(\frac{125}3-\frac{27}3\right)=\frac{392\pi}3=410.501$$
For rotation about the $y$-axis, disc integration gives
$$V=\pi\int_{-4}^4x^2\,dy$$
$$=\pi\int_{-4}^4\left(\sqrt{9+y^2}\right)^2\,dy$$
$$=\pi\int_{-4}^4(9+y^2)\,dy$$
$$=\pi\left[9y+\frac{y^3}3\right]_{-4}^4$$
$$=\pi\left(36+\frac{64}3+36+\frac{64}3\right)=\frac{344\pi}3=360.236$$

Comment: Thanks! so there wasn't a need to translate the graph in the first place?

Comment: @sallyg Yeah, no need to translate. About the $x$-axis the solid's a cylinder with two depressions. About the $y$-axis it looks like the body of a yo-yo.